# delete qtabwidget

Tags: c++, qt4.8, qtabwidget

my program keeps crashing with returncode 0.
The cause is somewhere in my qtabwidget but I can't find the error.

```
 QTabWidget *layout_tabs;

// create tabs
void myclass::fill_tabs(void)
{
  kill_tabs(); // remove old tabs 
  layout_tabs = new QTabWidget();

  // program adds content into a few tabs, like:
  // widgets created, content created, put into layout, put into widget..
  layout_tabs->addTab(widget, "description");
  layout_tabs->addTab(widget2, "description2");

  layout_tabs->show();
}

void myclass::kill_tabs(void)
{
  if(layout_tabs==nullptr)
    return;
  layout_tabs->hide();

  QWidget *window;

  for ( int i=layout_tabs->count()-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        window = layout_tabs->widget(i); // remember widget
        layout_tabs->removeTab(i); // remove tab
        free(window); // remove widget
    }

  free(layout_tabs); // remove qtabwidget
  layout_tabs=nullptr;
}
```

the filltabs() function is used a few times. The old tabwidget is destroyed and a new is created.
It does not matter if I don't delete the tabwidget, but remove only the tabs. The program still exits with returncode 0.

Answer (score 1):

You call `free(layout_tabs)` but you allocate it with `operator new()`.  You should deallocate it with `delete layout_tabs` instead.  I don't see how your `window` variable is allocated but you should check if it too should be deallocated with `operator delete()`, or if your `QTabWidget` owns its memory (i.e. if it is responsible for managing that memory).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed` to false.

```
#include <QApplication>

// ...

qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed (false);
```

Or you can go and set the container for your tabs (the main window/ main widget) to have the property of `Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` set to false.

```
myWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);
```

Either of those should fix it.  Also returning with "0" is not a crash.  Zero typically indicates a normal exit.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I forgot to mention that the main windows does not close. The tabwindow is a separate window to show results of a calculation. When I quit my program by shutting the main window, the program 'crashed with returncode 0' as kdevelop says. So it it not really a 'normal end' as kdevelop otherwise says.

Comment: ok I solved the problem. I should use layout_tabs = new QTabWidget(0) ( not QTabWidget() ! ) in de constructor and not delete the tabwidget anymore, only remove the tabs.